# Run function after first one is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need text in h5 to start appearing after whole text in h1 is done.
Do i need a function counting time it takes to end first function to delay it or is there any easier way? can it be done with one typeWriter() function?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var text = $('.test').data('text');
  var text2 = $('.test2').data('text');
  
  function typeWriter(text, n) {
  if (n < (text.length)) {
    $('.test').html(text.substring(0, n+1));
    n++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      typeWriter(text, n)
    }, 100);
  }
}

function typeWriter2(text, n) {
  if (n < (text.length)) {
    $('.test2').html(text.substring(0, n+1));
    n++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      typeWriter2(text, n)
    }, 100);
  }
}


function process(callback){
 typeWriter(text, 0);
  callback(text2, 0);
}
process(typeWriter2);

  
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="test" data-text="Augue ac adipiscing quis"></h1>
  <h5 class="test2" data-text="arcu auctor! Elementum."></h5>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method more flexible by passing in a whole bunch of options. Then to do two in sequence, you provide a callback, and use it to invoke the function a second time on completion.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var text = $('.test').data('text');
  var text2 = $('.test2').data('text');

  function typeWriter3(options, cb) {
      if (options.index < options.text.length) {
          $(options.selector).text(options.text.substr(0, options.index+1));
          options.index++;
          setTimeout(function() {
              typeWriter3(options, cb);
          }, 100);
      } else if (typeof(cb) === 'function') {
          cb();
      }
  }

  typeWriter3({
      index: 0,
      text: text,
      selector: '.test'
  }, function() {
      typeWriter3({
          index: 0,
          text: text2,
          selector: '.test2'
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="test" data-text="Augue ac adipiscing quis"></h1>
  <h5 class="test2" data-text="arcu auctor! Elementum."></h5>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```